# Trying to perform selenium testing using chrome driver but facing issue with below error while executing in cli as headless browser

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, headless

- tests are performed in ubuntu machine (cli)

> <<< FAILURE!
>
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed
>   to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Both google-chrome and chromedriver are installed under `/usr/bin/`

Code sample:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
"/usr/bin/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("file:///" + destFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by starting chrome at --no-sandbox mode (which is not the best practice). So it's a permission issue.